# config nginx to run php in sub folder

Tags: php, nginx

i'm installing limesurvey on my server.

due to nginx was originally used as proxy to my golang server on the machine, i have to keep php running in sub folder.

the root dirctory  of limesurvey on disk is /limesurvey.

so i have nginx config as below:

```
location /limesurvey {
    alias    /limesurvey;
}
location ~ /limesurvey/.*\.php$ {
    alias /limesurvey;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

but when i visit http://example.com/limesurvey/index.php,  it shows：

```
  opendir(/limesurvey/limesurvey/tmp/assets/1086beef): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

what i want to archive is:
http://example.com/limesurvey/*  goes to local file system (/limesurvey/*)

all other query goes to 127.0.0.1:8080

how can i config nginx to fix this issue?

Comment: problem is not in your nginx config, it's in your index.php code. You try to open something with url / src set to "/limesurvey/tmp/assets/1086beef" but you have to open with url / src set to "/tmp/assets/1086beef"... ! Show index.php code ;)

Comment: @Julo0sS I'm installing [limesurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/), I guess there will be a lot of code like this in the project.    Is there any way I can do with the nginx config, to solve the issue?

Comment: One side, you say the server that when user wants to go to your website root, server automatically goes to root/limesurvey. And, other side (in index.php) you tell something to go catch information from root/limesurvey. BUT you have already defined (server side) root as being root/limesurvey. This results in a mistaken root/limesurvey/limesurvey/... thing!

Comment: IMO : you do not have to configure /limesurvey... You just have to configure your root correctly. And then if the user goes in root/limesurvey, then it will just work fine...

Comment: i've edited the question. since i already have, and must keep the proxy_pass setting on web root, I have to make sub folder run php only.

Comment: seems i should use alias not root,but the problem is still there.

Comment: did you restart nginx...? ^^ root or alias is not the point, it's the value you give the problem. Leave your "location ****" like this, and change root /limesurvey to root/ just to give it a try

Comment: location /limesurvey {
      root   /;
    }
      location ~ /limesurvey/.*\.php(.*)$ {
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        root /;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }
still same

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ /limesurvey/.*\.php(.*)$ {
access_log /1.logs;
    root /lms/;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /lms$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location /limesurvey {
  root   /lms/;
}
```

and also move /limesurvey folder to /lms/limesurvey folder